# I can't play my music on my iphone 5s any more

Tags: music

I have about 100 songs on my phone and I used to be able to play them and I see all the songs under music on my phone but they are faded like I can't play them. Why did this happen and how do I fix it?

Comment: We need more information to help you.  What type of device are you using and what version of iOS is it running?  Does this happen to all songs or just some.  Does it happen with headphones or on the phone speaker?

Comment: Would you be willing to post a screenshot (or two)?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds as though you may have an interrupted iCloud login, and that you may have accidentally dismissed the warning that normally appears. Assuming latest system, use the Settings>iCloud to reestablish it. Clicking on the account name should cause the phone to prompt you for your iCloud password. After entering it correctly, the songs should appear playable again. You may also have to do that in Settings>iTunes and App Store. You'll need to log in with the same account used to purchase the songs. You may also need to check that Use Cellular Data is enabled.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the above, I opened "my music" select playlist, hit "new" then start selecting songs, once you have selected what songs you want in your playlist, go back to the my music app and select untitled playlist and those songs you selected should be there. Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Go into settings select I tunes and App Store select use mobile data